# How to uninstall software using batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, wmi, uninstall

I want to uninstall a software by calling a bat file. It must be automatically, without entering any parameters during the uninstallation. 
How to make the bat file which would be able to uninstall software by name?

PS: I know the perfect method using WMI, but it requires user input:

```
WMIC
product where name="software" call uninstall
```

Comment: This is going to depend on how the program was originally installed. MSI, InstallShield, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think WMIC commands can be run from a single line which should make it easier to add to a batch file.  And by adding **/nointeractive** then it should disable prompting as well.  Try something like this:

```
wmic product where name="software" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Comment: This is awesome...will this exit gracefully if there's no software with the name specified (if you've already uninstalled it, for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Although that may be possible for certain specific installations it's not possible to do so for all installations. As Zypher has already indicated, it will depend a great deal on the installation system used. It will also depend on whether that system allows for a "quiet" uninstall.

I really can't image a "perfect method using WMI" but congratulations if you've found one. On the other hand, you've also discovered one of the things that will get in the way of achieving your goal.